# Firebase/Parse.com alternative using MySql

Tags: mysql, parse-platform, firebase

I love using Firebase or Parse as a backend of my mobile apps, but one of my customers wants us to install the backend on their in-house servers, and store data in their MySql cluster.
I'm free to use any technology, such as node, apache + php etc, but i'm obliged to use MySql as a DB.

All noBackend project i found are storing data in noSql databases, and that's out of discussion for my customer. 
What turn-key alternatives do I have?
A paid alternative is ok.

Thanks

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I'm suggesting you to take a look at jexia.com. There is already a plan that will be on soon that will let you host the data in any kind of DB and place as you or your client wants.